# Kafka Client Bind IP (Secondary NIC)

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, bind, nic

I have a .NET Kafka client (using librdkafka via a Confluent's .NET client) running on a physical server with two network interfaces active. One is 10G and the other is 1G, both of them have static IP addresses assigned. Our networking team handles the configurations and is unlikely to change their practices for one application so I'd like to handle this client-side. I should also mention that the 1G interface and 10G interfaces are on the same network.

Since my Kafka cluster (3-node) is all 10G, I would like to require my application's consumer to bind to the 10G IP address. Looking through all of the documentation, I can't find anything about defining this on the client.

I would like to avoid any "hacky" solutions like setting Kafka to deny any non-whitelisted IP addresses or DNS tomfoolery.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be sure.., Do you know if your server is doing interface bonding (means the traffic will load balance between each interface, though, it's unlikely to do binding on different speed interfaces..)?

If not, as your two interfaces are on the same network, it means you will only use one interface to reach the network (except if you have exotic routing config). This interface will be defined by your default route.
If it's a Linux server, you can do as follows :

```
ip route
default via X.X.X.X dev YOURDEFAULTINTERFACE
```

If it's the 10G, you have nothing to do and you can be sure it will use this interface.
If not, you cannot do anything Kafka side, as it's purely OS settings side. Your Kernel will forward any traffic through this default interface.
Again.. I insist on the fact that this is because both your interfaces are in the same network.
If you have any doubts with this, please share your network configuration in details ( result of ip addr and ip route)

Yannick